# finding menu hierachy > wp_get_nav_menu_items

Tags: theme-development, menus

Hi I am building a menu using the code listed here.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items

Is there a way to suss out the menu hierarchy. As i can not debug this, it is difficult for me to see what wp_get_nav_menu_items actually returns.

```
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
```

or

```
<?php $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu, $args = array()); ?>
```

Is there a listing that describes the objects returned via wordpress functions?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever i find myself not sure what kind of data is returned by a function i use my simple ready made `var_dump_pre()` function which i use heavily in developments, simply paste it in your theme's functions.php file.

```
function var_dump_pre($obj){
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($obj);
    echo <'/pre>';
}
```

**Usage**

say i want to see what `wp_get_nav_menu_items` actually returns:

```
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id); 
var_dump_pre($menu_items);
```